# ¿Cómo consumir un servicio .asmx sin agregarlo como referencia?

Tags: c#, .net, webservice, .asmx

Buenas tardes, mi problema es que tengo un proyecto donde tengo agregados varios servicios agregados por referencia, se podría decir que de la forma común, pero actualmente me están pidiendo que se puede cambiar hacia algo mas dinámico. Uno de los detalles es que no podemos manipular los servicios solo consumirlos.
Mi proyecto web está desarrollo en .net c#, espero se comprensible mi explicación si me falto algún detalle solo díganlo.  De antemano gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes generar una clase proxy sin necesidad de crear una referencia al servicio, este es un ejemplo:

wsdl.exe /out:d:/MiClase.cs /order http://localhost:8080/MiServicio.asmx

Eso te genera un archivo cs que puedes importar en tu proyecto